# Fullscreen is black with Fontconf warnings after updating Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, fonts

After having upgraded Ubuntu, I had the problem where Ubuntu was stuck in a login loop. To try fix it, I used answers from 
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

Now, when I try to start up Ubuntu, where the login screen would usually appear, I have a full black screen with white fontconfig warnings:

```
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 61: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf", line 96: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-loma-synthetic.conf", line 12: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf", line 21: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-baekmuk.conf", line 10: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-baekmuk.conf", line 23: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 9: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 22: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 26: Having multiple <family> in <alias> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 31: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-nanum.conf", line 40: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
  # Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-fonts-unfonts-core.conf", line 11: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not works as expected
```

I do have access to a full screen command-line. 
Many people suggested the commands:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.config/fontconfig
mv $HOME/.fonts.conf $HOME/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
```

however, it says

```
mv: cannot stat '.fonts.conf': No such file or directory.
```

I also tried editing the `/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf` file as root:

```
sudo nano /etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf
```

and changed the line that says

```
<include ignore_missing="yes" deprecated="yes">~/.fonts.conf</include>
```

to

```
<!-- <include ignore_missing="yes" deprecated="yes">~/.fonts.conf</include> -->
```

I rebooted Ubuntu and the same Fontconfig errors are present.

How do I fix this?